# Building a Python Library: Cannot Import Name 'TestClass'

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I'm building a python package with the following structure:

py_directory

- directory1

  - script1.py (contains Class1)
- directory2

  - script2.py (contains Class2)
- automation_class.py
- setup.py

When I have packaged my code into a .whl and try to import a class:

```py
from py_directory.directory2 import Class2
```

I get the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Class2' from 'py_directory'
```

However if I just run

```
import py_directory
```

I don't get an import error, but I still can't access the classes within that directory.
It seems like it's reading the file not the class and I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: I think you meant to do `from py_directory.directory2.script2 import Class2`.

Comment: maybe miss the file: __init__.py in each folder..

Comment: Do I need an init at the same level as the setup.py?